# How to monitor multiple locations and show a message separately for each path?

Tags: c, linux

In this code, I am trying to monitor a filesystem. But the problem that I am facing is that I am monitoring two locations at the same time and I made an `if-statement` for this purpose like `if(wd1)`(file created in pathname1) then notify me about the first path and `if(wd2)`(file created in pathname2) then notify me about the second path.

But even if I create a file in the `pathname2`, it gives me the message of `pathname1`. How to make this `if-statement` work?

```
int main(){
  int length, i = 0, fd, wd1, wd2;
  char buffer[EVENT_BUF_LEN];
  char pathname1[200] = "path/to/location1";
  char pathname2[200] = "path/to/location2";

  fd = inotify_init();    
  wd1 = inotify_add_watch(fd, pathname1, IN_CREATE);
  wd2 = inotify_add_watch(fd, pathname2, IN_CREATE);
  length = read( fd, buffer, EVENT_BUF_LEN ); 

  while(i < length){     
      struct inotify_event *event = (struct inotify_event *)&buffer[i];
      if(event->len){
          if(event->mask & IN_CREATE){
             if(wd1){
               printf("New file is '%s' created in %s\n", event->name, pathname1);
             }
             else if(wd2){
               printf("New file is '%s' created in %s\n", event->name, pathname2);
             }
          }
      }
      i += EVENT_SIZE + event->len;
  }
  inotify_rm_watch(fd, wd1);
  inotify_rm_watch(fd, wd2);
  close(fd);
}
```

Comment: Unless your first call to `inotify_add_watch()` returns 0, `wd1` is always going to be true...

Comment: I am not a linux expert, but wd1 and wd2 seem to be two handles to the watch notification for me. So wd1 will be a valid value everytime you check it, and wd2 would also be a valid value, but you dont check it...  Where

Comment: @WolfgangRoth How to make this if-statement work because as I explained above that even if I create a file in `pathname2`, it gives me the message of `pathname1`

Comment: What do you expect `if(wd1){` to do? You need to compare two values: `if(event->wd == wd1){`

Comment: @Skywifibrand: i do not know anything about the inotify_add_watch function, so i cannot give you any advise. Shawn said basically the same what i was thinking about. Check the function documentation and how to use it.

Comment: @Cheatah Thank you! You solved my problem. I forgot using `event->wd == wd1`. Instead I just used `wd1`

Comment: you may post the solution and mark it as answer

Comment: or vote to close as a typo, because it's a silly little mistake, kinda like a typo

Comment: (Typo close message: "While similar questions are on-topic, this one was answered in a way that is unlikely to help future readers". I think this applies here)

Answer (score 0):

The following line is not what you want:

```
if(wd1){
```

This line only checks for the return value of the `inotify_add_watch` function, and this function is very unlikely to return 0.
What you most likely meant is the following:

```
if(event->wd == wd1){
```

This compares the previously returned value of wd1 with the watch file descriptor of the event that was triggered.